# Testing API in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-5.3

I am new in Laravel and I am a bit confused on how to test my api in 5.3.  I read the docs and I saw this kind of examples but I don't know if I applied the examples correctly.  Anyway, I'm always getting an ErrorException

[Error Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Xh6U.png)

I have this one in UserTest.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class UserTest extends TestCase
{
   /**
    * A basic test example.
    *
    * @return void
   */
   public function testLoginSuccess()
   {
       $this->post('http://127.0.0.1/identificare_api/public/api/user/login', ['email' => 'identificare@gmail.com', 'password' => 'identificare']);
   }
}
```

and I tried this one also, still no go.

```
$this->json('POST', 'user/login', ['email' => 'identificare@gmail.com', 'password' => 'identificare']);
```

here's my route

```
Route::post('user/login', 'UserController@login');
```

Is it correct to do it this way? If no, what's the correct way of testing my api?

Comment: I'm guessing you have an error in your error handler! The 'e' is possibly a missing parameter in a try-catch block? I don't know what the app/Exceptions path is - that's not typical in Laravel, so if this is a custom class path of yours, I suggest you look into the line 47 the error is at. Is the $e being declared like catch($e Exception)? ... Then you can debug the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct way to call the post is

```
$this->post('/user/login', array('email' => 'identificare@gmail.com', 'password' => 'identificare'));
```

or

```
$this->call('POST','/user/login', array('email' => 'identificare@gmail.com', 'password' => 'identificare'));
```

use an echo and exit in the login function and check whether test hitting the controller function.
It will be easier if you share a dummy code of your controller function ,because we could n`t figure out what this variable $e. Which should be in controller.